# ASP MVC 3 is it possible to identify the <input> id in the controller [post] method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, controller

I'm using a  so as to edit an object, with an `<input type="submit">` for validation

I've also another input, `type="button"` with an `onclick` event for the cancel button (with a redirect). However, this use a JS call, which I'd like to avoid.

I'd rather prefer to process the validation or cancel choice within the controller, so as to be NoScript compliant.

So is it possible to retrieve, within the controller post method, the id of the `<input>` that was clicked in the `<form>`?

Thanks

Comment: Is your `<button>` type="submit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the name of your

```
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" />
```

Then in your controller:

```
if(Request["submitButton"] != null) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you, but if your cancel button does a redirect, it should end in a GET, and your submit button does a POST, that's how you should difference both request.

Check the [HttpPost] attribute in controller action methods.

Comment: +1 That was going to be my answer -- implement the cancel as a hyperlink, not as a button.

Comment: I know an hyperlink would be the best solution, however, for design and accessibility in house rules, it's not possible

Comment: yep, an hyperlink would be simpler, and maybe better semantically. but maybe he just need to keep the button look&feel, or there's another restriction we don't know.

Comment: you can use a button if you want, but put onclick="document.location.href='http://....", that would result in a GET too, just as an hyperlink

Comment: yes, but that's a JS call, so it won't be OK for accessibility

Comment: but didn't you said you are already using an onclick event on the cancel button? Or you're doing POST-REDIRECT-GET on cancel? That sounds much worse. If you don't JS the obvious solution is to use an hyperlink as olivehour suggested first.

Comment: I said that in current version, I use a onclick event, but that I'd rather use a submit. I'll rewrite the question in a clearer way.

Comment: OK, I just had to say that I see a few problems on that, posting all the form data innecesary, an extra request processed on the server, a controller action with a little strange behavior (although you can use an action filter to abstract that), this would be much simpler using an hyperlink, but I wont insist as you said house rules, regards